# Disable toggle switch in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

This script is designed to map the location between two cubicles so that people in large office buildings can figure out where they need to go to get to that other person. I've almost got it...

I have two different dropdown menus I'm working with.

By default, the dots on the page display.

Each dot corresponds to a name on the dropdown list.

When you select the name under the first dropdown, the other dot will disappear, and then if you select the name under the other dropdown, the first one disappears.

What I want to happen is - When both names are selected from the dropdowns, then both dots are showing at the same time.

I can get one or the other, but not both.

**Here's the JS I have to toggle between the two...**

```
$('#mapMe').change(function() {

        var selectedMeChoice = $('#mapMe option:selected').val();
        if (selectedMeChoice == 'ALL'){
            $('a.dot').slideDown(1000);
        }else{
            $('a.dot[mechoice = "'+selectedMeChoice+'"]').slideDown(1000);
            $('a.dot[mechoice != "'+selectedMeChoice+'"]').slideUp(1000);
        }

    });


$('#mapThem').change(function() {

        var selectedThemChoice = $('#mapThem option:selected').val();
        if (selectedThemChoice == 'ALL'){
            $('a.dot').slideDown(1000);
        }else{
            $('a.dot[themchoice = "'+selectedThemChoice+'"]').slideDown(1000);
            $('a.dot[themchoice != "'+selectedThemChoice+'"]').slideUp(1000);
        }

    });
```

I think it has something to do with the slideUp/slideDown function, but I can't figure it out...

There's a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/XvHJS/5/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't distinguishing between "them" and "me" in any way, so you're hiding the other one which should be shown.  Try something like this, to only hide the correct dots:

```
$(".me").removeClass("me");
$('a.dot[mechoice = "'+selectedMeChoice+'"]').addClass("me").slideDown(1000);
$("a.dot").not(".me, .them").slideUp(1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XvHJS/10/

In this way you will hide only a previous "me" and not hide everything, including an active "them".

Comment: Here's a better idea of what I'm trying to do. I think originally I needed to add more dots to make the effect better. Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/XvHJS/8/embedded/result/). You'll see how when you select a name, the other dots are removed... But what I want is to select a name from one menu, then another name from the other menu, and have just those two show, and not the entire page.  Does that make more sense? I apologize if my first issue was cryptic.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  From your first question, "What I want to happen is - When both names are selected from the dropdowns, then both dots are showing at the same time.  I can get one or the other, but not both. " ... this is what my answer addresses.  I'm not sure what you mean now by "not the entire page".

Comment: Here's the actual site I'm working with [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/ohe-map-i.html)... When you get there, you'll see dots lined up all over the map. (disregard the dots on the right - as they're not assigned to people yet). When you select a name from "Where am I?"... then all dots disappear except that dot. What I want to happen is when you select a name from "Where are you?"... then I want both dots to show, but not every dot that shows by default.

Comment: @webfrogs you can still do something very similar.  See my update.

Comment: You nailed it with that extra class. Thanks James!

Comment: Now that we have this part nailed down... how much more difficult would it be to add a search function to this... so users don't have to scroll through a list of names?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.dot[mechoice != "'+selectedMeChoice+'"]').slideUp(1000);
```

Is also removing those which have no `memchoice` at all, including those with `themchoice`.
I would suggest using different classes `dotme` and `dotthem` instead.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm not very clear as to what you're suggesting.